# Shell Bash, Como passar dado do shel como parametro

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

eu preciso executar um arquivo arquivo1.sh,porem alem disso preciso pegar o dado que vem depois dele, por exemplo: arquivo1.sh 171.55.8.45, esse ip que vem depois, na mesma linha do arquivo, antes de apertar enter, preciso que esse ip seja lido e passado como parâmetro para outra ação dentro do código, mas sem utilizar o **read**.

Comment: Mostre o codigo do arquivo1.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu script recebendo o *IP* como parâmetro fica assim:

```
#!/bin/bash

VARIAVEL_IP="$1"
# $1 se refere ao primeiro parâmetro passado na command line

# TESTE
echo "IP passado como parâmetro: $VARIAVEL_IP"
```

Caso deseja utilizar outros parâmetros, basta passar a frente do seu scipt e fazer a chamada referente a posição do parâmetro.

**Exemplo:**

***Command Line:***

```
Script.sh "p1" "p2" "p3"
```

***Script:***

```
#!/bin/bash

# Atribuindo p1
POSICAO_01="$1"
# Atribuindo p2
POSICAO_01="$2"
# Atribuindo p3
POSICAO_01="$3"
```

Answer (score 3):

Existem variáveis padrão que guardam os parâmetros que você passa para um script. Se você rodar

```
$ ./myscript.sh param1 param2
```

Então,

```
$0 = myscript.sh 
$1 = param1
$2 = param2
```